# There is no sound come from video.Ubuntu 16.04.How to fix?

Tags: sound

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.When I first open my computer everyday, in ubuntu there are no sound come from video.That is why i searched and find a way to fix it.The way is when i entered ubuntu I have to open terminal and write a commad- **alsactl restore** and press enter. It fix the sound problem.But this is the matter of sorrow that everytime when i entered ubuntu, I have to write that command.So, is there any way to fix it, I don't want to write that command in terminal everytime.

Comment: Not sure it will fix it but u may want to upgrade to 18.04 or 20.04 as support for 16.04 comes to an EOL in April of this year.

Answer (score 0):

found a problem close to yours, see https://www.linuxliteos.com/forums/sound/i-have-to-run-alsactl-restore-in-the-terminal-at-every-boot/

Hope it will help !